# Next.js empty style tag in <html> element on pages other than root

Tags: html, next.js

Next.js adds an empty `style=""` tag to the `<html>` element on any page that's not the rootpath. Does anyone know why?

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Visit https://62fvu4-3000.csb.app
- Click on *about*
- Inspect the page and look at the `<html>` element

It does not happen when you visit the about page directly.

Unfortunately I couldn't find anything related in the next.js documentation.